# Add from one grid view to another

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I have I have 2 grid views. Gridview1 has details of Bicycles which are available for rent. Gridview1 also has a button. When button on gridview1 is clicked the concerned row should get added on to gridview2

Gridview2 is bikes selected from gridview1. I have tried writting that code but it doesn't work.

Below is my code

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

            int id = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["IndBikeID"].Value.ToString());
            SqlConnection con = Database.GetCnn();
            con.Open();
            string command = "select * from Bike_IndividualBike Where Bike_IndividualBike.Status = 'Available' AND IndBikeID=" + id + "";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(command, con);

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {

            }
        }
```

I am not sure what to put in the foreach loop.

Also why do we need int id variable?

Can someone please help me. The project is for renting bicycle.

Comment: What do you mean by _doesn't work_? You get any exception or error message?

Comment: Do both grids have same columns??

Answer (score 0):

You can have an `<asp:LinkButton../>` in your `GridView1`.As you have mentioned in `GridView1` there is a list of available Bicycles and you have populated that gridview appropriately.

On the click of the `LinkButton` you can make an `INSERT` query by adding that `id` into your *selected* bicycles table.

Once you have done that, you can populate the `GridView2` by using the query which will only select the *selected* bicycles.

As, a postback will occur on the page(because of the click on the link-button), the `GridView1` will get the data according to the query(which is **only available** bicycles) and thus the *previously selected* bicycle will not be shown in `GridView1` and will be populated inside your `GridView2`(given you have written queries as I have mentioned!)

Answer (score 0):

I think using SqlDataReader might be easier

```
con.Open();
string command = "select * from Bike_IndividualBike Where Bike_IndividualBike.Status = 'Available' AND IndBikeID=" + id + "";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(command, con);

using (SqlDataReader read = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    while (read.Read())
    {
        object[] values = new object[read.FieldCount];
        read.GetValues(values);
        dataGridView2.Rows.Add(values);
    }
```